# sum of squares of integers

Tags: haskell, recursion

Ok This is a homework question but **I'm not asking for a solution to how its done**

What I want to ask is what it is asking me to do?

> The sum of the squares of integers in the range `m:n` (where `m` ≥ `n`) can
>   be computed recursively. If there is more than one number in the range
>   `m:n`, the solution is to add the square of `m` to the sum of the squares
>   in the range`m+1:n`; otherwise there is only one number in the range
>   `m:n`, so `m == n`, and the solution is just the square of `m`.
>
> a. Define the recursive function `sumsquares` to carry out this
>   computation. As always, draw up a series of test data showing the
>   expected output, and then test the function.

I know I have to write a recursive function called `sumsquares` but I dont quite understand what it means by "The sum of the squares of integers in the range `m:n` (where `m` ≥ `n`) can be computed recursively".

This is the code I have so far, Would this be correct??

```
sumsquares :: Integral a=> Int -> Int -> Int
sumsquares m n
 |m > n = error "First number cannot be bigger than second number"
 |m==n = m*n
 |otherwise = m*n +sumsquares (m+1)n
```

Someone else came up with this answer

```
sumOfSquaresFast :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
sumOfSquaresFast lo hi
    | lo > hi   = error "sumOfSquaresFast: lo > hi"
    | otherwise = ssq hi - ssq (lo - 1)
    where ssq x = div (2 * x^3 + 3 * x^2 + x) 6
```

But I do not understand the bottom part, the ssq and the div functions?

Comment: Lets say, `m` is 1 and `n` is `5`, your program has to find `1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2`. If `m` is 3 and `n` is 3 then your program has to find `3^2`. The thing is, you have to use recursion to do this.

Comment: Thank you thefourtheye, I understood what I needed to do with your explanation :)

Comment: `sumOfSquaresFast` is definitely not recursive and uses the Square pyramidal number [Square pyramidal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number). To calculate from a to b, you calculate the sum of squares from 1 to (a-1) and you substract it from the sum of squares from 1 to b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to take two numbers, e.g. `1` and `10`, square each number between them (inclusively), and then take the sum of that.  So you'd want some function like

```
sumOfSquaresBetween :: Int -> Int -> Int
sumOfSquaresBetween m n = ???
```

Now, you have to use recursion, so this means that `???` is going to be some expression that uses `sumOfSquaresBetween`.

Now here's the trick: If you know `sumOfSquares n n`, then how would you find `sumOfSquares (n - 1) n`?  What about `sumOfSquares (n - 2) n`?  Can you generalize this all the way to `sumOfSquares m n` for `m <= n`?  If so, then you've just performed your desired algorithm, but in reverse.

Hope this hint helps.

Comment: ic ic, how do I highlight my code in the comments... i can never do it

Comment: @Harry What is `mn`?  I'm going to guess it's because you used a single quote ' instead of the back tick ` to format your code in this comment.  I'd suggest editing your question with your attempt instead, it's much easier to format code.

Comment: Well, it's pretty close, but not quite.  For `sumsquares 1 3` you should get `1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 == 14`.  What do you get for this input?

Comment: hmmm somehow i got 18?

Comment: My hint here is this should be the sum of squares.  You can use normal multiplication for this (and it's probably faster, but you shouldn't worry about speed here), but you can also use the `^` operator for raising numbers to a power.  Try both ways and see if you can spot the problem.

Comment: I have no idea where the problem could be, I can't even work out how it came to the answer 18

Comment: @Harry Are you actually taking the square of each number or are you calculating something else?  Is `m * n` always the square of `n`?

Comment: im missing the sum of the square numbers? this is why that it doesn't return the correct number?

Comment: @Harry you're calculating the sum of numbers, but they aren't all squares. In the last guard you should be adding m*m rather than m*n. For consistency it wouldn't hurt to do that in the last two guards.

Comment: If i was adding the sum of the numbers, I still dont know how I ended upa t 18? 1+1+2+2+3+3 == 12, then 1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 == 14, so how did 18 even get returned? I still can't get this code to work =.=

Comment: @Harry you're calculating 1*3+2*3+3*3. Replace your last line with `otherwise = m*m + sumsquares (m+1) n`. I said you were summing numbers, I didn't say which, just that they weren't squares. Your otherwise case is only true when m and n aren't equal, so m*n is not necessarily a square number.

Comment: I tried that, and now when i input sumsquares 1 3 i get 11

Answer (score 0):

"The sum of the squares of integers in the range m:n (where m ≥n) can be computed recursively."

Let's break this apart....

---

"integers in the range m:n"

is the set of integers starting from m, going to n

[m, m+1, m+2, ....n]

ie-

```
integers in the range 4:8 = [4,5,6,7,8]
```

---

"squares of...."

As you probably know, the square of a number `x` is `x*x`, so

```
squares of integers in the range 4:8 = [16, 26, 36, 49, 64]
```

---

"The sum of...."

add them

```
The sum of the squares of integers in the range 4:8 = 16+26+36+49+64
```

---

".... can be computer recursively"

Well, you have to understand recursion to get this....

Any function that contains itself in the definition is recursive.  Of course you have to be careful, if done incorrectly, a recursive function could lead to infinite loops....

For Ints, (N-1) recursion is common....  If you can use the calculation for `(N-1)` to evaluate the calculation for N, the computer can run down the numbers until a known value is hit (typically 0).  This is better seen with an example.

```
let func n = sum of integers from 0 to n
```

(this is like your problem, but without the squares part)

if you know the value of `func (n-1)`, you can easily compute the value of `func n`

```
func n = n + func (n-1)
func 0 = 0
```

The computer will use `func 0` to compute `func 1`, `func 1` to compute `func 2`, etc, all the way to N.

---

Recursion has two common (but actually pretty different) uses...  First, as shown above, it allows for very clean function definitions.

Secondly, it is often used in mathematics to prove truths over all integers (ie- to prove something is true for all ints, prove it is true for 0, then prove if it is true for N, it is true for N+1....).

Comment: Thank you for your indepth answer, I think I managed to do my code now, Is the code I put in my edited question correct?

Answer (score 0):

Really, the best way to solve this problem is also the easiest: use library functions.

```
sumsquares :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
sumsquares m n = sum (map (^2) (enumFromTo n m))
```

You just enumerate the numbers from `n` to `m`, square each of them, and take the sum of the results.  Trying to solve this problem in with direct recursion just makes things needlessly complicated.

**Exercise:** Write your own versions of the library functions used in this answer.

```
-- | Generate the list of all values in the given range.  Result is inclusive.
enumFromTo :: Enum a => a -> a -> [a]

-- | Apply a function individually to each element of the argument list,
-- and collect the results as a list, respecting the order of the original.
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]


-- | Calculate the sum of a list of numbers.
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
```